# How does Tarski's continuity axiom qualify as such?

Tags: geometry, logic

In Tarski's system of geometry, he describes his continuity axiom as follows:

> To obtain an appropriate set of axioms, we start with an axiom system
>   which is known to provide an adequate basis for the whole of Euclidean
>   geometry and contains β and δ as the only non-logical constants.
>   Usually the only non-elementary sentence in such a system is the
>   continuity axiom, which contains second-order variables X, Y,...
>   ranging over arbitrary point sets (in addition to first-order
>   variables x, y,... ranging over points) and also an additional logical
>   constant, the membership symbol $\in$ denoting the membership relation
>   between points and point sets. The continuity axiom can be formulated,
>   e.g., as follows:
>
> $ \forall XY \{ \exists z \forall xy[x \in X \land y \in Y \to β(zxy)] \to \exists u \forall xy [x \in X \land y \in Y \to β(xuy)] \} $

He describes the function β as:

> [T]he formula β(xyz) is read y lies between x and z (the case when y
>   coincides with x or z not being excluded)...

This continuity axioms appears to exemplify the idea of a Dedekind cut, which Dedekind applied to the geometry of lines:

> If all points of the straight line fall into two classes such that
>   every point of the first class lies to the left of every point of the
>   second class, then there exists *one and only one point* which
>   produces this division of all points into two classes, this severing
>   of the straight line into two portions. (Richard Dedekind. *Essays on
>   the Theory of Numbers*)

According to my interpretation, this principle would exclude the number line consisting of only the integers, for example, because $X$ and $Y$ could be defined as $X = \{x | x \leq 2\}; Y = \{y | y \geq 3\}$, leaving *more than one* possible value between 2 and 3. For that reason it seems that any formalization of the principle would have to exclude the possibility for more than one value between the upper bound of $X$ and lower bound of $Y$.

For that reason, I would expect Tarski's axiom to be something like the following:

$ \forall XY \{ \exists z \forall xy[x \in X \land y \in Y \to β(zxy)] \to \exists u \forall xy [(x \in X \land y \in Y \to β(xuy)) \color{maroon}{ \land \forall w[β(xwy) \to w=u]}] \} $

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about this?

Comment: I think that it is simply a question of "generality"; if we consider e.g. the segments $[0,4]$ and $[8,12]$ we cannot impose that there must be only one point in between... The antecedent of the axiom says : For **every** sets of points (segments) $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ is to the right of $Y$ with respect to an "origin" $z$, there is **at least** a point $u$ "separating" $X$ and $Y$". The axiom is aimed at avoiding the well-known case (see Dedekind) : $X = \{ x \mid x^2 < 2 \} ; Y = \{ y \mid y^2 > 2 \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. I don't understand your point. If there is more than one value between the segments, they would *not* be continuous. Therefore, to establish continuity, it has to be shown that there is "one and only one point" as Dedekind said. The segments [0,4] and [4, 12] would be continuous on the real number line because 4 is the only number that can be said to be between them.

Comment: Tarski's theory is FOL and the individual variables stay for *points*; a *line* is a particular set of points. In the meta-theory we can use set variables like $X$ to "describe" set of points but in the formal theory we have only formulae with a parameter $\phi(x)$. Thus, in the meta-) we can say that : $x \in X$ **iff** $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Thus, in the meta-, we can abbreviate with $X_{\phi} = \{ x \mid \phi(x) \}$. Having said that, a line is a set of collinear points; thus, again in the meta-, we may abbreviate $\text {line} (\phi) = \text {line} (X_{\phi})$ **iff** $\forall x,y,z [x,y,z \in X_{\phi} \to \beta(x,y,x)]$.

Comment: But this relies on the "intended" interpretation... In general, the axioms consider "sets" of points whatever. If e.g. we consider two sets of points "scattered" on the $x$-axis : e.g. $X= \{ 1,2,4 \}$ and $Y= \{ 3,5,6,7 \}$, it is simply not true that "there exists $z$ (like e.g. the "origin" $0$) such that : for **all** $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ : $\beta(z,x,y)$".

Comment: Correct to speak of "ray of points"; thus, for every "ray" $r$ from $z$ and subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $r$ such that every point in $Y$ is to the right of every point in $X$ (with respect to $z$), there exists **at least one** point $u$ "separating" $X$ and $Y$. The key-point is "at least one": if we consider the $x$-axis with only rational coordinates and the sets $X= \{x \mid 0 < x \land x^2 < 2 \}$ and $Y = \{ y \mid y^2 > 2 \land y < 4 \}$ it is not true that there is a "point" (i.e. a rational $= \sqrt {2}$) that "separates" them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. The only reason I would see that there exists no such $z$ is because of the fact that your set $X$ overlaps $Y$. Otherwise, all $x \in \{1,2,4\}$ would fall between the origin and $Y$ if it were changed to $Y = \{5,6,7,8\}$. There are only three values for x, and they all fall between the origin and the smallest value of $Y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Concerning your last comment, why are you specifying only rational coordinates? For an adequate axiom of continuity, there has to be the possibility that $u$ can have values other than those contained in $X$ and $Y$, because otherwise the axiom would be tautologous. There is *always* at least one $u$, such as the maximum value $X$ or the minimum of $Y$, that would satisfy $β(xuy)$. You say that the key point is "a least one", but I just don't see how. I believe the key point is "one and only one" as Dedekind said, because, otherwise, there's a gap between $X$ and $Y$.